# SQL Cursor Alternative

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

Need some advice on improving/rewriting the below query. In summary, I have got a table which I am trying to recursively loop through to generate a parent-child relationship.

For example, the table has:

```
PAT_ID 1

+-------+------------------+------------------+
| EP_ID |    START_DTTM    |     END_DTTM     |
+-------+------------------+------------------+
|     1 | 01/12/2018 10:00 | 02/12/2018 15:00 |
|     2 | 03/12/2018 10:00 | 10/12/2018 15:00 |
|     3 | 04/12/2018 10:00 | 06/12/2018 15:00 |
|     4 | 07/12/2018 10:00 | 09/12/2018 15:00 |
|     5 | 11/12/2018 10:00 | 13/12/2018 15:00 |
|     6 | 12/12/2018 10:00 | 12/12/2018 15:00 |
|     7 | 01/12/2019 10:00 | 02/12/2019 15:00 |
+-------+------------------+------------------+
```

Desired Output:

```
+--------+-------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| PAT_ID | EP_ID | PARENT_ID |                                        LINK_TYPE                                        |
+--------+-------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|      1 |     1 |         0 | 'Parent'                                                                                |
|      1 |     2 |         1 | 'Child' (Rule for child is that START_DTTM is less than 24 hours of parent EP_ID)       |
|      1 |     3 |         2 | 'Inner' (Rule for inner is that START_DTTM is between START_DTTM and END_DTTM of Child) |
|      1 |     4 |         2 | 'Inner'                                                                                 |
|      1 |     5 |         0 | 'Parent' (doesnt qualify as child or inner for any row)                                 |
|      1 |     6 |         5 | 'Child'                                                                                 |
|      1 |     7 |         0 | 'Parent                                                                                 |
+--------+-------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

~~~
I have attempted to write the logic using a cursor which seems to be returning rows fine but the base table has over 10m rows so its unlikely to complete before my retirement which unfortunately has 30 more years to go :). Need the community's expert advice on how can I approach this query (i have tried while loop which was slower than cursor).

Thanks in advance!

```
IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#PARENT') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #PARENT
END

IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#CHILD') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #CHILD
END


CREATE TABLE #Parent (
    EP_ID INT
    ,ID VARCHAR(20)
    ,PAT_ID VARCHAR(50)
    ,START_DTTM DATETIME
    ,END_DTTM DATETIME
    ,CT_DESC VARCHAR(100)
    ,CT_CODE VARCHAR(10)
    ,PARENT_EP_ID INT
    ,PARENT_ID VARCHAR(20)
    ,LINK VARCHAR(20)
    ,PROCESSED INT
    ,PARENT_EP_SEQ INT
    )

CREATE TABLE #CHILD (
    EP_ID INT
    ,ID VARCHAR(20)
    ,PAT_ID VARCHAR(50)
    ,START_DTTM DATETIME
    ,END_DTTM DATETIME
    ,CT_DESC VARCHAR(100)
    ,CT_CODE VARCHAR(10)
    ,PARENT_EP_ID INT
    ,PARENT_ID VARCHAR(20)
    ,LINK VARCHAR(20)
    ,PROCESSED INT
    ,CHILD_EP_SEQ INT
    )


INSERT INTO #PARENT
SELECT deip.EP_ID
    ,deip.ID
    ,deip.PAT_ID
    ,START_DTTM
    ,END_DTTM
    ,CT_DESC
    ,CT_CODE
    ,0
    ,''
    ,'Parent' AS LINK
    ,0 AS PROCESSED
    ,row_number() OVER (
        PARTITION BY deip.PAT_ID ORDER BY START_DTTM
        ) AS PARENT_EP_SEQ
FROM dbo.deip
INNER JOIN dbo.dEP ep ON deip.EP_ID = ep.EP_ID
dbo.RE ep.STATUS IN (
        'A'
        ,'D'
        )
    AND ep.RECORD_STATUS = 'A'
    AND
    event_type = 'Active'
    AND CT_CODE <> '10'

PRINT 'Parent Done'

DECLARE @PARENT_EP_SEQ INT
DECLARE @PAT_ID INT
DECLARE @EP_ID INT
DECLARE @COUNT BIGINT

DECLARE ChildCursor CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD
FOR
SELECT PARENT_EP_SEQ
    ,PAT_ID
    ,EP_ID
FROM #PARENT
where PROCESSED = 0

OPEN ChildCursor

while 1 = 1
BEGIN
    -- And then fetch
    FETCH NEXT
    FROM ChildCursor
    INTO @PARENT_EP_SEQ
        ,@PAT_ID
        ,@EP_ID

    -- And then, if no row is fetched, exit the loop
    IF @@fetch_status <> 0
    BEGIN
        BREAK
    END
    INSERT INTO #CHILD
    SELECT C.EP_ID
        ,C.ID
        ,P.PAT_ID
        ,C.START_DTTM
        ,C.END_DTTM
        ,C.CT_DESC
        ,C.CT_CODE
        ,P.EP_ID AS PARENT_EP_ID
        ,P.ID
        ,'Child' AS LINK
        ,0 AS PROCESSED
        ,row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY C.PAT_ID ORDER BY c.START_DTTM
            ) AS CHILD_EP_SEQ
    FROM #PARENT p
    INNER JOIN #PARENT C ON p.PAT_ID = c.PAT_ID
    dbo.RE P.PAT_ID = @PAT_ID
        AND P.EP_ID = @EP_ID
        AND P.PARENT_EP_SEQ = @PARENT_EP_SEQ
        AND P.EP_ID <> C.EP_ID
        AND P.PARENT_EP_SEQ <> C.PARENT_EP_SEQ
        AND datediff(hh, isnull(p.END_DTTM, getdate()), C.START_DTTM) BETWEEN 0
            AND 24
        AND p.PROCESSED = 0
        AND c.CT_CODE <> '10'
    ORDER BY p.PARENT_EP_SEQ

    DELETE P
    FROM #PARENT P
    INNER JOIN #CHILD c ON p.PAT_ID = c.PAT_ID
        AND p.EP_ID = c.EP_ID

    UPDATE #PARENT
    SET Processed = 1
    dbo.RE PAT_ID = @PAT_ID
        AND EP_ID = @EP_ID
        AND PARENT_EP_SEQ = @PARENT_EP_SEQ
END

CLOSE ChildCursor

DEALLOCATE ChildCursor

PRINT 'Child Done'
```

After thought: I thought of using recursive/heirarchial CTE but i don't have a key that determines the relations. The parent->child association is what i am trying to generate.

Comment: Given the syntax in the question, I’m going to assume this is SQL Server. Based on that, check out Recursive CTEs.

Comment: I have tried CTE but not sure how to evaluate each row against the other row in the group using cte

Comment: I am Assuming with such amount of data index are present ,before anything else you have to check the queries with their index

Comment: try using straight sql as an alternative to loop/cursor logic

Comment: Yep. Index are there and poor performance is due to cursor.

Answer (score 0):

You could multi-thread your CURSOR approach, since this sounds like a one-off and not something you'll be doing over and over again.

Edit your CURSOR code with a filter that will have it work on about 500k rows, launch it, open another window and add a filter that will work on rows 500,001-1million, launch it, etc.

I bet it will be done before you've come up with a CTE/set-based approach for this logic.

Comment: Not a bad idea. let me try that

Comment: Nope, no luck. The batch process is equally bad.

Comment: Did you try it with NOLOCK to make sure the different threads weren't blocking each other?